# Adding elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, append, jquery-append

What would be the best way to add this element and its children to the DOM with jQuery?
Let's say that the div that I need to append has an id wrapper.

```
<div id="menu">
<a href="#" id="link1" data-speed="600" data-easing="easeOutBack">About</a>
<a href="#" id="link2" data-speed="600" data-easing="easeOutBack">Updates</a>
<a href="#" id="link3" data-speed="600" data-easing="easeOutBack">Producer</a>
<a href="#" id="link4" data-speed="1000" data-easing="easeInExpo">Performer</a>
<a href="#" id="link5" data-speed="600" data-easing="easeOutBack">Speaker</a>
<a href="#" id="link6" data-speed="1000" data-easing="easeInExpo">Endorser</a>
<a href="#" id="link7" data-speed="1000" data-easing="easeInExpo">Mentor</a>
<a href="#" id="link9" data-speed="600" data-easing="easeOutBack">Press</a>
<a href="#" id="link10" data-speed="600" data-easing="easeOutBack">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Anyone care to help?

Thanks,

Mirko

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a *very* basic question. We expect you to have done a small amount of research before you ask a question. It's likely you'll find the answer quite easily via a quick Google search, or by looking at the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com) (tip, see [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append))

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Yeah i know it is basic, but i'm concerned how to add inner anchor elements and their attributes.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('<div id="menu">...</div>').appendTo('#wrapper');
```

Just be sure that the HTML in the first part doesn't have line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('<div id="menu">
<a href="#" id="link1" data-speed="600" data-easing="easeOutBack">About</a>
<a href="#" id="link2" data-speed="600" data-easing="easeOutBack">Updates</a>
<a href="#" id="link3" data-speed="600" data-easing="easeOutBack">Producer</a>
<a href="#" id="link4" data-speed="1000" data-easing="easeInExpo">Performer</a>
<a href="#" id="link5" data-speed="600" data-easing="easeOutBack">Speaker</a>
<a href="#" id="link6" data-speed="1000" data-easing="easeInExpo">Endorser</a>
<a href="#" id="link7" data-speed="1000" data-easing="easeInExpo">Mentor</a>
<a href="#" id="link9" data-speed="600" data-easing="easeOutBack">Press</a>
<a href="#" id="link10" data-speed="600" data-easing="easeOutBack">Contact</a>
</div>').appendTo('#wrapper');
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I just needed to figure out that no spacing was allowed inside the #menu div.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use soem method do append, but it will depend where you want to add these elements, look this:

`.append()`: http://api.jquery.com/append/
Insert to the end of element

`.prepend()`:  http://api.jquery.com/prepend/
Insert to the start of element

I hope it helps

Comment: Your descriptions are incorrect. `.append()` adds **to the end** of the element, not after. Likewise, `.prepend()` adds **to the start** of the element, not before.

Comment: Yes, I correct, but I know how to use everyone. Sorry, my native language is not enlgish!

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$('#menu').append('#yourIdToInclude')
```

Comment: Is that going to work with an element that isn't yet part of the DOM? Question asks about appending **to the DOM**, which implies that it's not.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#menu').appendTo('#elementinwhichtoappend')
```

Comment: to the downvoter: the fact itself he want to inject some data into the dom inside a **specific element** doesn't exclude *apriori* (except further clarification) that he already has that markup injected elsewhere into the dom. Otherwise it would be logical think that he should have the markup presented in form of string (stored in variable)

Answer (score 0):

Assume the target div has an id `target` and you have the html in a string named `html`

`$("#target").append(html)`

Comment: No quotes around `html` - you'll just be appending the actual string html to that element, rather than the contents of the variable `html`.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist : oops!! fixed it. thanks for pointing that :)